# How to secure critical information in Sitecore applications

Tags: configuration, security

We've a requirement to secure certain passwords and userIDs. These can't be in config files.
Wanted to know if Sitecore has any tools or any best practices defined for such data storage?
Any keystore system which can be used?

Comment: Generally, usename password is stored under aspnet_Membership table, so you can create a separate DB to store these as well.

Answer (score 1):

### If User/password is huge counts and users are not related to sitecore sites

1. You have to handle with custom implementation. I have a similar requirement to
   manage users with sitecore system.

   My github project have the end to end user management functionality. User sign-
   up/login/Reset-password/Authenticate user/JWT token issuer functionality.

   **Reference git project** : https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore-bugger/tree/master/SitecoreBugger

   **C#-UserManagement modules**: [here](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore-bugger/tree/master/SitecoreBugger/SitecoreBugger/Security)

   **SQL mdf/script files** : [here](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore-bugger/tree/master/SitecoreBugger/SitecoreBugger/Releases/Sitecore%20Bugger%201.0/Market%20place%20release/SCB%201.0%20-%20Sitecore.NET%209.3.0%20(rev.%20003498)/DataBase/SCB/mdf)

### If User/password is huge counts and users are related to sitecore sites

1. Why you cant handle with sitecore user management it self ?
   Save the users with custom domains. Validate the users by sitecore APIS. Don't
   add any roles to the users , unless it requires.

### If User/password is very less counts below 10

1. Azure key vault.

   **Reference :** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#code-try-0
2. Windows credential manager

   **Reference :**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550674/2632619